# Run the selenium python script parallelly on chrome and msedge browsers

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, automated-tests

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\seldriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\edgedriver\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

I want to run the code simultaneously on chrome and msedge browsers

I am getting the error

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found

Comment: Ehh, this won't work. You assign 2 different drivers to the same variable "driver". You want to run the same test, using 2 different drivers? Are you using a pipeline/yaml/build server? Do the tests need to run at the same time, or is your requirement: I got 1 test, run it on 2 different browsers?

Comment: I am not using any pipeline/yaml/buid. This is a very basic code of logging in. i want to run the test on 2 different browsers at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 drivers and run the tests side by side. Edge requires a different command to create the driver.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\seldriver\\chromedriver.exe") 
driver2 = webdriver.Edge("C:\\edgedriver\\msedgedriver.exe") 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver2.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

This means duplicating every step you do. But what you MAYBE want, create a variable driver inside a for loop. The first time you assign Chrome, the second time Edge. It will not run in parallel,  but saves 50% on maintenance.